# get hidden input value from previousElementSibling

Tags: javascript

I have more than one csrf token field in my view because I have more than one place where a post request happens.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
<button type="submit" class="button editItem" data-id="<%= product._id %>">Edit Item <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
```

After playing around with different DOM navigation it seems like I can access the entire input with `previousElementSibling` but I can't extract the actual value ie: the csrf token from it.

```
const editListingBtn = document.querySelector('.editItem');
if (editListingBtn) {
  editListingBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const csrf = editListingBtn.previousElementSibling.querySelector('[name="_csrf"]').value;
```

And trying this gives me a cannot read property 'value' of null.

Comment: Where is the `editListingBtn` defined in this code?

Comment: The error implies you are not finding it as it is producing `null`

Comment: @PrashantZombade, editListingBtn is defined as the name of the button that has an event listener attached. I edited my original question

Comment: @RyanWilson, ah. Can you make that your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @user8463989 Added as an answer per your request, my only concern with even the modified code, is do you have more than one button which has a `className` of  `editItem`??

Comment: @RyanWilson, no. I only have one button with that class name.

Comment: @user8463989 Ok. Then you are safe. Just making sure, because if you had more than one, you may not get the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use `querySelector`, `previousElementSibling` should give you the hidden input, change to this:

```
const editListingBtn = document.querySelector('.editItem');
if (editListingBtn) {
  editListingBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const csrf = editListingBtn.previousElementSibling.value;
```